# How to add a hyperlink or a mail link to React Native Paper Paragraph?

Tags: react-native-paper

How to add a link to react-native-paper `<Paragraph></Paragraph>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

For Android the [dataDetectorType](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#datadetectortype) works with RN Paper [paragraph](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/paragraph.html) as well.
`<Paragraph  dataDetectorType="link">http://youraddress</Paragraph>` or `<Paragraph  dataDetectorType="email">mail address</Paragraph>`

But for iOS and Android both the easiest way to achieve this is using the [Linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking).

```
import { Linking, } from } from 'react-native';
```

then

```
<Paragraph 
    style={{ color: 'blue', textDecorationLine: 'underline', }} 
    onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mailto:address')}>
       mail
</Paragraph>
```